# PERN How can I handle async post request?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postgresql

Backend :

```js
app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = db.query("SELECT id , email , password FROM users");
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log(result.rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      if (
        email === result.rows.email[i] &&
        password === result.rows.password[i]
      )
        res.send(true);
      else res.send(false);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

Frontend :

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import FormPart from "../components/FormParts";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  const apiCall = async () => {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/login", { email, password })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log("handle submit");
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/login", { email, password })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormPart
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <FormPart
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Log In</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I just learned the basics of React and wanted to make a simple login recording application using the Perm combination, but I encountered such a problem.
How can I handle with async post request?
I tried to make async axios function on React but it didn't work.
Firstly I didn't work with database and when I log my email and password on Backend everything was okay. After that I added my database with async function, then I can't get any data from backend, also I can't send response to frontend. I just got `undefined` for my console.log()'s on backend.

Comment: Please be more specific about *what* didn't work *how*. what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes sure , Firstly i didnt work with database and when i log my email and password on Backend everything was okay. After that i added my database with async function then , i cant get any data from backend also i cant send response to frontend. I just got undefined for my console.log()'s on backend

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the await to get the data from the db then you can loop to the result and perform your logic like this.

```
app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await db.query("SELECT id , email , password FROM users");
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log(result.rows);
    let check = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      if (
        email === result.rows.email[i] &&
        password === result.rows.password[i]
      ) {
          check = true;
          break;
        }
    }
    if (check) { 
      res.send(true);
    } else {
      res.send(false);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: +1                                               for also not trying to send the response in multiple places (or not at all)